# How to execute cURL requesting which requires to upload file in Golang?

Tags: go, curl

I have a cURL request as follows.

```
$(curl --request PUT --upload-file "<path to catalog file on your local machine>" "<presigned URL>")
```

Let's say that I have to upload a `bin/test.txt` file with the `presigned URL` being `https://www.someurl.com`

I execute the command in my terminal
`curl --request PUT --upload-file "bin/test.txt" "https://www.someurl.com"` and it works fine.

How do I write a piece of Golang which does the same? I have tried

```
cmd := exec.Command("curl", "--request", "PUT", "--upload-file", fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\"", catalogPath), fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\"", presignedURL))
err = cmd.Run()
```

but found no success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang JSON/HTTP request like curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379156/golang-json-http-request-like-curl)

Comment: You do not need to execute `curl` to do this. Please read the docs on [`net/http`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) and may be a couple of tutorials, try to do a simple HTTP PUT request from Go and open another question if/when you'll have some _particular_ problem with your attempted solution.

Answer (score 0):

I see one obvious problem preventing that `curl` call from working properly, one quite possible and another one also possible.

The obvious problem is that string quoting — such as executing `curl … --upload-file "bin/test.txt" …` — in interpreted by the shell which is to execute the command. Quoting — using either double or single quotes — is used to inhibit interpreting of otherwise special characters by the shell; chiefly it's used to prevent the shell from splitting a string into separate "words" on whitespace characters or their series.
The key takeaway is that the command run by the shell after it's fully parsed the command to be executed (and interpreted the quotes) does not "see" these quotes because they are removed by the shell.

`os/exec.Cmd` calls the specified program directly and does not "pass it through" the shell. Hence if you include double quotes into the command-line parameters of the program to execute, they are passed to that program, unchanged. This means, `curl` were to try to find the file named `test.txt"` located in the directory named `"bin` — which is most probably not what you expected.
The same applied to the URL.

The second — possible — problem is that your call relies on the [current directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) of your Go program because you pass a relative path to `curl`.
This might or might not be a problem but you might check this anyway.

The third problem is that you might want to pass your URL through the ["percent escaping" algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) before passing it to `curl`.
You might look at `PathEscape` and `QueryEscape` functions of the [`net/url`  package](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url).

---

Two pieces of advice follow.

First, I would try very hard not to call out to `curl` to perform such a ridiculously simple task. Go has excellent support for making HTTP requests (and serving them, FWIW) in its standard library, and PUTting a file is really a no-brainer with a solutions googleable in, like, five minutes.

Second, if, for some reason, you intend to stick with calling `curl`, consider passing it some options to make it fail loudly on errors — otherwise you're doomed to be in that „but found no success” situation in your attempts. For instance, consider passing `curl` the `-s` and `-S` command line options (together).

Answer (score 0):

that's not how you quote shell arguments, that would break if your argument starts with or ends with `\`  or `"`, the proper way to quote shell arguments on unix would be

```
func quoteshellarg(str string) string {
    if strings.Contains(str, "\x00") {
        panic("argument contains null bytes, it is impossible to escape null bytes in shell arguments!")
    }
    return "'" + strings.ReplaceAll(str, "'", "'\\''") + "'"
}
```

and with that, just

```
cmd := exec.Command("curl --request PUT --upload-file " + quoteshellarg(catalogPath)+ " " + quoteshellarg(presignedURL));
```

... at least that's how to do it on unix systems. as for how to do it on Windows, it seems [nobody knows for sure, not even Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/twistylittlepassagesallalike/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way)